# Formatting with Python / Pandas

Tags: python

I would like to paste a list of IDs and have it output the IDs in a SQL ready format.

for example:

I would paste this list of IDs:

```
12345
43212
43566
35667
```

and I want it to output the list like this:

```
'12345','43212','43566','35667'
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this with python?

Comment: What do you consider "SQL ready format"? What format do you paste the IDs in? What have you tried? Why hasn't it worked as expected?

Comment: I want to paste the IDs in a vertical format as if I was copying them from an excel column. I tried attaching them all to one variable but that is where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: I know how to do it by putting the IDs into a csv and making a loop to assign the SQL formatting, but I'm hoping there's a way to paste the IDs straight into the python console.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you have asked for -

type:

```
s = '''
```

then paste your content and close with:

```
'''
```

then you can split the string. Here is how it look on my interpreter:

```
>>> s = '''12345
... 43212
... 43566
... 35667'''
>>> s.split()
['12345', '43212', '43566', '35667']
```

Comment: Thanks!! this is perfect! I didn't know you can assign multiple rows to one variable by using '''

Comment: There's no need to specify `'\n'` -- if you just use `split()`, it'll safely handle the possibility of extra spaces and `'\r` and other types of whitespace floating around.